# MySQL return null on AJAX call in PHP OOP

Tags: php, ajax, oop

I'm trying to retrieve data from MySQL from AJAX call here is my code.

When I call AJAX from front-end then it will return `null`. Same query will work when I run it in phpMyAdmin.

here is my class file

```
    class Bpay{

        private $db;
        private $fm;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new Database();
            $this->fm = new Format();
        }

        public function getAllPaymentRecord($borderid,$month_of,$year_of){

            $border_id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $borderid);
            $month      = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $month_of);
            $year       = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $year_of);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM mms_border_payable WHERE border_id = '".$border_id."' AND month_of = '".$month."' AND year_of =  '".$year."' ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result = $this->db->select($query);
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Handler file like this. Where I send my AJAX request and get JSON data from class

```
    include 'Bpay.php';

    if(isset( $_POST['borderid'] )) {

        $recordArray = array();

        $regBpay = new Bpay();

        $borderid       = $_POST['borderid'];
        $month_of       = $_POST['month_of'];
        $year_of        = $_POST['year_of'];

        $recordArray['borderid'] = $borderid;
        $recordArray['month_of'] = $month_of;
        $recordArray['year_of'] = $year_of;

        $recordArray['paymentRecords'] = $regBpay->getAllPaymentRecord($borderid,$month_of,$year_of);

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($recordArray);
    }
```

here is my ajax call

```
    var borderid = $("#border").val();
    var month_of = $("#month_of").val();
    var year_of = $("#year_of").val();


    $.ajax({
        url: '../classes/recordHandler.php',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            borderid : borderid,
            month_of : month_of,
            year_of : year_of
        },
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

got result like this

```
    {
        borderid:"3"
        month_of:"2"
        paymentRecords:
            current_field:null
            field_count:null
            lengths:null
            num_rows:null
            type:null

        year_of:"2018"
    }
```

I can't understand why this happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do some debugging: What does the generated query look like and if that is what you expect, what does the `select()` method look like?

Comment: This is select() - --

public function select($query){
    $result = $this->link->query($query) or 
    die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
      return $result;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }

Comment: @DipokChakraborty you can always edit your question, and it would make it clearer for the readers to see the related code as an Edit in the question rather than on the comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. i got my answer. i tried to get data without fetch.now its clear to me. thanks again.i'm learning php yet.here is my code

```
public function getAllPaymentRecord($borderid,$month_of,$year_of){

    $border_id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $borderid);
    $month      = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $month_of);
    $year       = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $year_of);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM mms_border_payable WHERE border_id = '3' AND month_of = '".$month."' AND year_of =  '".$year."' ORDER BY id ASC";

    $result = $this->db->select($query);
    $resArray = array();

    if($result){
        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($resArray, $data);
        }
    }
    return $resArray;
}
```